# Did a moderator confuse me, the flagger, with the person I was flagging?

Tags: support, flags, moderators

I got a moderator response for one of the flags I raised (about being rude), and it looks like moderator confused me with the person I was reporting being rude (the other alternative is that I am wrong about meaning of 'rude').

I do not see any way to reach back to this particular moderator and attempt to resolve the situation, to see if it was a case of confusion (or if it is not, to educate myself on where exactly I was wrong). Is there some way?

Comment: _"it looks like moderator confused me with the person I was reporting being rude"_ I doubt it, unless the moderator thought you reported yourself?

Comment: @George that's a bit more convoluted, there were actually two flags raised by me.  I do not want to give too much detail here since it is a delicate thing.

Comment: You could always raise another custom mod flag asking for clarification. Or wait here until a mod chimes in. Since it's a "delicate thing", raising another flag might be the safer path.

Comment: Oh yes! I see now. I read your edited comment and you used said you seem to know a lot about B. S. I thought you meant the rude version. You meant Bjarne S. Sorry that was my mistake.

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes, thanks for looking into it. In the first version of the comment I used initials, and upon reading it immediately realized that it doesn't look great, and than edited again.

Comment: Thanks for being understanding. Do you want me to write an answer?

Comment: @YvetteColomb only if you do not have more urgent/pressing matters. I am glad it is all resolved.

Comment: Can't you respond to moderator messages? Or are there multiple types of mod messages?

Comment: @TylerH it was a helpful message to a flag. So when you see the flag history the OP can read the message.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Ahh that kind of message, gotcha. I was thinking like the kind that shows up with a notification and is in the message center.

Comment: @TylerH it was not a warning or anything like that. The account is in good standing.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

That was my mistake.

There were some comment flags, that coincided with your custom flag. I happened to handle them around the same time.

The other person replied that you had edited a rude comment and when I checked it, it read

> You seem to know a lot about B.S. ...

I assumed you were insulting the OP, you in fact meant Bjarne S.

Your account is in good order, which is why I only made that reply in a post flag (which I marked helpful). The comment seemed out of character.

I'm really sorry.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this isn't necessary, but just in case any non-native speakers are left confused after reading this answer, note that "B.S." is a common abbreviation for "bullshit".

Comment: @MarkAmery should I include that in the post?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I think it's probably obvious enough... anyone confused enough to search for it will find the answer right away, I'm sure.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Don't or well flag it for being rude! You will get banned! :P

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes true :)

Comment: Leak from the C++11 committee mailing list: "Who came up with the idea to remake the auto keyword? BS!"  "Oh wow, lets implement it right away then!"

Comment: mods aren't robots. Else we wouldn't need them.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre does not compute... does not compute... */me starts sparking arcs of electricity...*

Comment: @JonClements well, except _you_ of course. Sorry for hurting your simulated feelings.

Comment: @Jean that's okay... I'm still not opening the pod bay door though... :p

Comment: "[Daisy, … Daisy, … give me your answer do…](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7WQ1tdxSqI&feature=youtu.be&t=27)

Comment: If you keep making these mistakes we'll have no choice but to hire you.

Comment: That's hilarious, I can imagine a lot of lame, nerdy jokes. One of these days I'm going to say something like "C++ is a 'B.S.' language." IRL and see what kind of looks I get.

Comment: I always thought that "bullshit" is just what you're using when when talking to your boss. "We identified the technological challenges and promptly resolved the related customer inquiry" is bullshit. "We figured out why it didn't work and submitted a fix" is *exactly the same*, but ... no bullshit.

Comment: @Marco13 Politicalspeak is a subcategory of BS, but one also tied to truth -- BS as a whole can include both "inflated" or over-articulated statements (like this comment, or your example) _and_ complete fabrications (like the claim that Julia Child was once hospitalized for swallowing a small rat whole).

Comment: @Tim no need to subject Yvette to such cruelty - be kind Tim I implore you! :)

Comment: @MarkAmery I am a non-native English speaker. Only until recently did I realize that BS is the abbrev of *bullshit*. Is it some recent invention (I hadn't seen it on SE until a few months ago) or long culture?

Comment: @iBug It's a known slang abbreviation, I had seen it before [here](https://www.abbreviations.com/term/339157). B.S. itself has multiple meanings and may cause misleading during conversation, depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks for doing what you do, Yvette. Your humanity, courtesy, and sensibility do you credit.

Comment: @iBug Good question! I wasn't sure, so I Googled a bit. It's at least as old as the web; using Google's ability to search by date to look for occurrences of the phrase "load of BS" before 1990 turns up a [scan of a 1988 edition of the BGSU Student Newspaper](https://scholarworks.bgsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.co.uk/&httpsredir=1&article=5776&context=bg-news) containing an article entitled *Prof Encourages Independent Thinking* in which the aforementioned prof is quoted using the phrase. Earlier than that, I don't know, since Google can't tell me and I wasn't alive.

Comment: Haha, that's gold.

Comment: My first thought was Bachelor of Science (I got confused because the sentence would be weird in that case), so at least I learned something new today. No matter how obvious something seems to be, it may not be obvious for other people, so I think it's always worth explaining it. Thanks!!!

Comment: This reminds me of my embarrassing "Guido" diamond moderator intervention on a Python language comment thread. Not realising that the "that Guido" being referred to was Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, and not in fact a racial slur. Not one of my better days :) Pretty sure @TimPost will remember this doozy.

Comment: @Kev We need to meet up in our eventual retirement and share a bottle over that one someday. I also wager that knowing who Guido is _remains_ the extent of your Python knowledge :P

Comment: @TimPost well Tim, I did dabble in Python a little, but you're correct. Luckily for all of us I'm back in my C#/.NET comfort zone :)